# Wpf touch events not working in windows 8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have a wpf desktop application. On windows 7 all touch events are working fine, but when I switch to windows 8.1, touch events don't work. Anybody knows why?

**Edit**

Here is my xaml code:

```
<Button Content="{Binding DisplayName}" Style="{StaticResource WindowButtonStyle}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="TouchUp">
            <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="OnTouchUpMenuButtons"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

and method in the viewModel:

```
public void OnTouchUpMenuButtons(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    // code  
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "When I switch to Windows 8.1"? Is the hardware identical, driver etc? Is it possible that your Windows 8.1 PC does not support touch, but actually has a touchscreen that emulates a mouse? Have you tried looking at the touchscreen drivers to see if you can configure touch/mouse emulation?

Comment: @Aron I have two versions of window - 7(32 bit) and 8. I did not installed additional drivers yet. When I run program under windows 7, touch events work, do the same by windows 8 - do not work...
How can I check, if my windows 8 emulates mouse?

Comment: Umm...if you haven't installed additional drivers its a pretty safe bet that you aren't running in touch mode. Install the touch drivers.

Comment: @Aron. Strange, but you are right! I thought windows installs touch drivers by default. After downloading and installing drivers everything works. Post it like an answer, so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've switched TouchUp events to PreviewMouseDown events and it works.